# Not assignable to android.app.activity in manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, classcastexception

I am facing problems in my manifest.xml I tried everything, but I don't understand why I get a "not assignable to app.activity" error. My expandablelist **is** an activity, not a fragment or something else. It just extends BaseExpandableListAdapter in order to show a ExpandableListView. Please help me.
Here is my belonging class:

```
         public class Expandablelist extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
        public Expandablelist(){

        }

        public Expandablelist(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                     HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
        }
```

Here is my mainactivity.java:

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        Expandablelist listAdapter;
       // ExpandableListView expListView;
          List<String> listDataHeader;
           HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // auf anderes xml layout zugreifen



            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


           // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
           // inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_expandablelist,null);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            final ImageButton generaldiscriptionbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            checkFirstRun();



            View expandablelistview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_expandablelist, null, false);
            ExpandableListView expListView = (ExpandableListView) expandablelistview.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);


            // get the listview
            //  expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);


            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new Expandablelist(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
            listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
            listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
            top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
            top250.add("The Godfather");
            top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
            top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
            top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
            top250.add("The Dark Knight");
            top250.add("12 Angry Men");

            List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
            nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
            nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
            nowShowing.add("Turbo");
            nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
            nowShowing.add("Red 2");
            nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

            List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
            comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
            comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
            comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
            comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
            comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
        }
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_basics) {
            // Handle the camera action
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Explain.class);
            startActivity(i);


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_explaination) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_materials) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Expandablelist.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

Here is my manifest.xml in which my Expandableist activity is declared:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- <activity android:name=".Explain"></activity> -->

    <activity
        android:name=".Explain"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <!-- <activity android:name=".BasicMaterials"></activity> -->

    <activity
        android:name=".BasicMaterials"
        android:parentActivityName=".Explain">


        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Explain" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Generaldiscription"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_generaldiscription"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Expandablelist"> // here is the error

    </activity>
</application>
```

**QUESTION: Why do I get an error in my android manifest xml? How can I solve that. The app works, but when I click on R.id.nav.materials on the sidebar, it crashes. It seems like it does not recognize my expandablelist as an activity, which I don't know why**

Here is my crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.cem.fahrzeugewaschen, PID: 25196
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.project/com.example.user.project.Expandablelist}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.user.project.Expandablelist cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.cem.fahrzeugewaschen.Expandablelist cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Comment: `My expandablelist is an activity` No, it's **not**. It's a **BaseExpandableListAdapter**. Because `It just extends BaseExpandableListAdapter`, instead of extending an **Activity**.

Comment: Ah, I understand, and how to solve that ?

Comment: post crash detail

Comment: Don't declare it in the Manifest. Classes don't need to be declared.

Comment: But it does not change the fact, that my expandablelist class is NOT an activitiy, so it can't be started with an Intent? Because I am starting the activity with an intent as you can see in the main.java

Comment: @Rotwang I removed it from the manifest, it does not work either.

Comment: At least, it's a good starting point. Now you should get a different logcat.

Comment: @Rotwang do you have any other hints for me ? Yes I get this error: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You are trying to use the ExpandableList Class **AS IF** it was an **Activity**: `Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Expandablelist.class);
            startActivity(i);`, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Ah, I understand. And how can I start my ExpandableList Class by clicking on the sidebar anyway?

Comment: My suggestion is to search for some ExpandableListView tutorial. It's a bit more complicated than a regular ListView, because you must handle the groups and the children.

Comment: @Rotwang well, this code is actually from a tutorial. I just added the feature to open this ExpandableListView by clicking on the sidebar by an intent, which seems to be wrong. The question is: How can I open a "Non" activity by clicking on the sidebar ?

Comment: That tutorial was either badly done. Or you skipped some steps.

Comment: The answer is that **you don't**. You can use a Class objects and methods, but you don't "open" it. You can show the objects it contains, if they have a 
 UI.

Comment: @Rotwang so do you have any code examples where I can see how to start a non activity from mainclass ?

Comment: There are a plenty, if you google for them. I actually don't have the time or lust to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Expandablelist.class);
startActivity(i);
```

This is wrong. The second argument must be an Activity.class

To show the list, create another activity which displays your `Expandablelist` in it's layout.

Refer [Android ExpandableListView Sample](http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you, can you give an example please, since I am new to this issue?

Comment: `create another activity` or a Fragment (so you wouldn't have to declare it in the Manifest).

Comment: Updated answer with tutorial link. @Blnpwr